# Error when trying to implement login script for visual basic application in visual studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Hi I'm sure this is an extremely simple issue to fix but i'm completely new to this and just following a tutorial online but i can't adapt the code for my uses. Basically i keep getting the following error when i try to use nvarchar instead of int for my username and password columns in my database:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

here is my code:

```
Public Class Login
    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(MyConnection.MyConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from [customer_login] where username=" + tbUsename.Text + " and password=" + tbPassword.Text + "", con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read Then
            MsgBox("you are logged on as" + tbUsename.Text + "put logged in home page here")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

edit: full error message is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid column name 'a123'.

Invalid column name 'a123'.
```

Comment: share the complete error please

Comment: We need the inner exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

single quotes are missing in your query

```
Public Class Login
    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(MyConnection.MyConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from [customer_login] where username='" + tbUsename.Text + "' and password='" + tbPassword.Text + "'", con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read Then
            MsgBox("you are logged on as" + tbUsename.Text)
            'put logged in home page here.show()
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I knew it would be a simple fix, thanks for your help! I will accept your answer as soon as i can!

Comment: That code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/). Please [use parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156151/).

Answer (score 2):

The code you have generates the following SQL:

```
select * from [customer_login] where username=user and password=pass
```

Where `user` and `pass` are the values entered in the text boxes.  That is not valid SQL, the values need to be quoted strings.  Or even better, they should be [named parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to prevent a class of attacks called [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), or just simply to prevent problems when a user has an apostrophe in name and your SQL statement built at run-time has an error in it as a result.

In the future, you should use a [Try .. Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) block to catch the exception and look at the contents of the exception in the debugger.  In this case, it would have quickly showed the error in your SQL statement.